# Connect Early 2015 Macbook pro to TWO HDMI monitors via Thunderbolt or USB

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have two free thunderbolt ports on my MacBook, and would ideally like to connect to two external HDMI monitors and have the macbook screen active as well.

I would like to extend the desktop and not just mirror the macbook. The closest adapter I've seen is [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sabrent-Thunderbolt-Supports-Monitors-TH-W3H2/dp/B07KB7NKR9?pf_rd_r=YCAM362EK7KY45YHEYX0&pf_rd_p=ad1dac78-5484-4aaa-bf17-e82a62646aa9&pd_rd_r=63996a57-11fb-4281-afe3-5db610f687d7&pd_rd_w=iZgjb&pd_rd_wg=kDhvS&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_d) but its only for later models. I do not have a thunderbolt 3 port and was hoping there is something similar but for thunderbolt 2.

What options are out there for me?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean the 13-inch version and not the 15-inch one.

According to [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.7-13-early-2015-retina-display-specs.html) "This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 3840x2160 on two external displays via Thunderbolt 2."

So as long as that max resolution is OK with you all you need is the appropriate cabling. And the one you found is for USB-C/Thunderbolt-3. Which is wrong for your Mac.

You need something similar to [this.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/DisplayPort-Adapter-Thunderbolt-Microsoft-Projector-Grey/dp/B07JDWR6W9/ref=sr_1_3?crid=ZC1646TW4WEL&dchild=1&keywords=thunderbolt%202%20to%20hdmi%20adapter&qid=1590265962&s=computers&sprefix=thunderbolt%202%20to%20hdmi%2Ccomputers%2C270&sr=1-3) Note I just snagged the first product on an Amazon search for "Thunderbolt 2 to HDMI adapter." I have no idea if that is a quality product or not.